# Error in makemigrations and migrate in pycharm using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Guy i was working on a django website i create a django website before also but this time when  ever i run command
Python manage.py makemigrations 
Its stop there no error nothing shows after this command 
Suggest me what to do 
And one thing i run the python makemigration blog
(Blog is app name here)
Its is working properly then but after this migrate command  will hang

Detail : I created a project name blogs 
And inside it i create a app blog
I am using postgresql database
After writing model class
I run the make migration command 
And it shows nothing and no other command i can write after this  as shown in image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfU5t.jpg)

Comment: i think you should change your postgresql port to 5432, also try a different virtual environment approach, first deactivate your virtual enviroment and then follow below commands.

Answer (score 0):

virtual environment using pipenv (follow below commands)

```
pipenv install django==3.0.1
```

then start the virtual enviorment

```
pipenv shell
```

then run your migrations command